# Jquery loads content too many times

Tags: jquery

With the help of someone I've created a script which loads JSON content in a page. The problem is that the content is loaded too many times instead of just once. This is the jquery function which is included in the head of the page in a file called main.js:

```
    function bakVorm(page,targetClass)
     {
     $.getJSON('http://shop.com/'+page+'/?format=json', function(data){
      var text = ''
      $.each(data.textpage, function(index, text){
      $(text).html('' + text + '').appendTo(targetClass);
});
});
```

On a product page I try to load the content in a div with this code:

```
$(function(){
bakVorm('vraag','.eigenschappen');
bakVorm('test','.verzendkosten');
});
```

Problem is that the content is loaded too many times in the corresponding div. Probably the script isn't stopped or something.

Any help is more then welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line

```
$(text).html('' + text + '').appendTo(targetClass);
```

You are adding the contents of text to each top level node in text, so if text is

```
 <div></div><p></p>
```

You'll end up with

```
<div><div></div><p></p></div><p><div></div><p></p></p>
```

So leave out the html part, and just have

```
$(text).appendTo(targetClass);
```

Comment: Ahh excellent! Thanks for your straight forward explaination. This makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Try emptying the targetClass in your code:

```
function bakVorm(page,targetClass)
 {
 $.getJSON('http://shop.com/'+page+'/?format=json', function(data){
  var text = ''
  $.each(data.textpage, function(index, text){
  $(targetClass).empty().append(text);
  });
});
```

Or try not using `append`

```
function bakVorm(page,targetClass)
 {
 $.getJSON('http://shop.com/'+page+'/?format=json', function(data){
  var text = ''
  $.each(data.textpage, function(index, text){
  $(targetClass).html(text);
  });
});
```